# Unable to understand the concept of android:gravity="fill"/ "fill_vertical"/ "fill_horizontal" for LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-gravity

I have the following code -

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button1"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button2"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

It gives me this output -

[image]

Now including the code -

```
android:gravity="fill"
```

or

```
android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
```

or

```
android:gravity="fill_vertical"
```

doesn't bring about any change in the output.

As I understand from some tutorials -

1. `fill` is used to fill the entire container both horizontally and vertically
2. `fill_horizontal` is used to fill the entire container horizontally
3. `fill_vertical` is used to fill the entire container vertically

Here, the container of `LinearLayout` is supposed to be the whole screen as `layout_width` and `layout_height` is set as `match_parent`

So why the gravity codes fail to have any impact?

Comment: I've never used the `fill_xxx` attribute, what effect you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I am just trying out this attribute and what is it's use, I have no practical use in mind as of now